# Is it safe to switch my bootloader to BURG?

Tags: bootloader, burg

I have Ubuntu 11.04 and Windows on a single hard disk. After reading it became clear that there are some options to have the bootloader changed into a screen with just the Ubuntu and Windows icon.

Right now i have some purple window (grub i guess) with i think 6 or 7 options to choose from;  Ubuntu, Ubuntu Safe mode, Windows loader and some others i cannot remember now.

Burg has some nice features, but i read about issues that people are not able to get into the system anymore.

What are my options?

Comment: It's safe if you do it right.

Comment: If you do it and something goofs up, don't panic.  There's generally a workaround.  But it's better to play with if you have a second computer or a liveCD to boot with in case of trouble.

Comment: Apart from BURG, there is also EasyBCD that works with the Windows bootloader. Both have been, reportedly, used successfully, that said, having a plan B is never hurts.

Comment: There have been a few similar questions. There is a very good answer to your question on https://askubuntu.com/questions/456587/how-do-i-replace-grub-with-burg?rq=1 I hope this is helpful, as it took me about five minutes to find it. I am sorry if this is not helpful, and was just a waste of your time.

Answer (score 3):

Burg is like a frontend to grub, so even if it fails the default grub will work. The only problem I had is during the first boot it tried to load a higher resolution than my monitor supports, so it only showed a black screen. But it still worked on the background, so I pressed enter and it booted normally. You can solve that installing grub customizer (a gui to configure grub and burg from the desktop) and rebooting. Or in the same burg screen pressing F2, up or down, and enter. Don't know if it's in the oficial repositories, but it's here:

```
https://launchpad.net/~danielrichter2007/+archive/grub-customizer
```

Just search all the burg related packages and install them on synaptic. If you have any problem, uninstall it and reinstall grub.

Comment: Why is BURG GRUB backwards? Is there any specific meaning to the "amazing" difference between the names?