# How do I replace GRUB with Burg?

Tags: bootloader, burg

I was just wondering if it was safe to install BURG on Ubuntu 14.04 and how do to it. It has not been updated for a while, so maybe the project is dead. If it's not possible to  replace GRUB with Burg, are there any alternatives to BURG.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To summarize from [this original post](http://www.unixmen.com/how-to-install-burg-boot-loader-in-ubuntu-1304-and-linuxmint/):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:n-muench/burg
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install burg burg-themes
sudo burg-install "(hd0)"
sudo update-burg
sudo burg-emu
```

To add grub-customizer:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```